# Partial plane transparency in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

Sorry if the title makes no sense at all, I'm not great with the actual terms for things and this is my first post here

I've been trying to make a sort of cut-out paper puppet show effect, where I draw the images in a seperate program and then move them around in Blender, but I can't figure out a way to get only the actual image to be opaque and the rest to be transparent if I make it an image texture on a flat plane. I know this is possible in cycles, but I don't think my laptop is powerful enough to render the whole animation in cycles. I was wondering if it's possible to do this in eevee, or if there's another work around? I'm using Blender 2.92

For reference, this is the type of effect I'm trying to do. I made this in cycles, but when it's in eevee the transparency just turns black

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: if you want transparency in Eevee you need to go into the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend, Shadow Mode > None

Comment: Hello, could you add the (unsatisfying) result in Eevee so we can see what's going wrong ?

Comment: @moonboots That works perfectly, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want transparency in Eevee you need to go into the *Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend, Shadow Mode > None*.